# MySql: how to handle conditional sorting

Tags: mysql, innodb

I have a stored procedure which takes in a couple of arguments. I need to return the result sorted in specific order based on the values of the arguments I receive as input. The issue I'm facing with that if I try to write a single query with switch-case block in order by clause, the query won't use any index. The sample structure is as given below

```
create table test_table(
f1 int,
f2 int,
f3 int,
key (f1),
key(f2)
);

-- now insert 2M rows in the table

-- query #1
mysql> explain select f1, f2 from test_table order by f1 desc limit 1000;
+----+-------------+------------+-------+---------------+------+---------+------+------+-------+
| id | select_type | table      | type  | possible_keys | key  | key_len | ref  | rows | Extra |
+----+-------------+------------+-------+---------------+------+---------+------+------+-------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | test_table | index | NULL          | f1   | 5       | NULL | 1000 | NULL  |
+----+-------------+------------+-------+---------------+------+---------+------+------+-------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

-- query #2
mysql> explain select f1, f2 from test_table order by f2 desc limit 1000;
+----+-------------+------------+-------+---------------+------+---------+------+------+-------+
| id | select_type | table      | type  | possible_keys | key  | key_len | ref  | rows | Extra |
+----+-------------+------------+-------+---------------+------+---------+------+------+-------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | test_table | index | NULL          | f2   | 5       | NULL | 1000 | NULL  |
+----+-------------+------------+-------+---------------+------+---------+------+------+-------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

set @a = 1, @b = 'd';

--query #3
mysql> explain select f1, f2 from test_table
   order by
    case when @a = 1 and @b = 'd' then f1
         when @a = 2 and @b = 'd' then f2 end desc,
    case when @a = 1 and @b = 'a' then f1
         when @a = 2 and @b = 'a' then f2 end asc
      limit 1000;
+----+-------------+------------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+---------+----------------+
| id | select_type | table      | type | possible_keys | key  | key_len | ref  | rows    | Extra          |
+----+-------------+------------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+---------+----------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | test_table | ALL  | NULL          | NULL | NULL    | NULL | 1995435 | Using filesort |
+----+-------------+------------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+---------+----------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

if you see query 1 or query 2 the explain outputs are as expected. But when I try to decide the sort column in runtime then it can't use any of the index. One alternative to achieving #3 would writing if-else blocks and writing individual queries there, but it will get ugly if there are multiple possibilities. In the above example it would lead to 4 similar blocks with different order by clause

My question:
**is there an alternate way to get query #3 done and what are its pros and cons?**

Comment: No, there is no other way then writing individual querys there (or at least indiviual endings, if you do it in php or dynamic sql). I don't think it would look more ugly or unreadable than your current query. And it's not only that your query cannot use indexes and will order by 2 columns instead of 1 (although 1 of these will be a constant `null`, mysql will still have to sort by it), your `order by` condition will be evaluated for every row, even if it looks like it is quasi-constant.

Comment: Say `NOT NULL` wherever appropriate.  Have an explicit `PRIMARY KEY`.  Use `INDEX(f1, f2)`.  But, if your `SELECT` is not the _real_ select, this advice may be useless.

Comment: Presumably, you meant `when @a = 2`??  (I made that change.)

Comment: @RickJames what do you mean by _real_ select? Also, adding a index(f1,f2) would still not work. Also @a = 2 or @a = 1 would have same effect

Answer (score 0):

The best way to handle variations to a `SELECT` is to dynamically construct the query in application code.

A common example is when the end-user can specify (or not) various things.  The app can construct a `WHERE` clause with the specified things.  It can even construct `IN` or `BETWEEN` clauses, etc, according to the user inputs.

Your case has to do with `ORDER BY`.  Again, the app code can quite easily construct the desired `ORDER BY`.  This will lead to an efficient query.

Alas, there is no construct within SQL to replace this.